# What part of my code is blocking hotkey combinations?

Tags: c#, winforms, background, launcher

I started on a mini-project in C# that was simply an invisible (or at least incredibly small) WinForm that opened applications of my choice when I used certain hotkey combinations (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num3</kbd> opened The Sims 4). I ditched the project when I realized that it would only work when the "invisible form" was open and selected in the taskbar, where I didn't want it to be. I recently made a mouse spasm prank for my brother on April Fools Day and used the following three lines to hide the form:

```
this.Hide(); //hides the form
this.Text = null; //hides the application from the task manager
this.ShowInTaskbar = false; //hides the application from the taskbar
```

I went back to the hotkey launcher and put these three (excluding the task manager one) into the "Form1_Load" event in the main code. When I began debugging, I noticed that they did indeed hide the form, but the hotkey combinations would not respond. What I ask is 1) Which of the two lines [1 and 3] is causing this conflict and 2) If I can, how can I resolve this?

Thank you for your time.

Note: Yes, I do know that you can make background applications using the Windows Service template, but I heard from someplace that it is incompatible with what I am using, Visual C# 2010 Express. I would have used it otherwise.

Comment: When you hide the form, you remove it's input focus. In order to intercept all keyboard events, you need to get a bit more low level, such as using: ``SetWindowsHookEx()`` as explained, e.g. here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not the code, any key wont register unless if you are using it while the form is in-focus (on the form itself), if you need something to respond to global keyboard and mouse events then you need to use windows hooks:

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it.